# Rsyncing full daily backup effiecentlly

Tags: linux, svn, rsync

I'm managing a server, Alpha (running Debian, and Fusion Forge (a web based project management system)) with ~200GB of svn repositories (around 200 different repositories).  And I'm trying to manage the daily backups of the data to a file sever Beta (running Windows, it has delta copy on it) that then handles all other backups.  The problem is right now I end up transferring all 200GB every day, and I'm not making good use of rsync.

Right now two full daily backups are stored on Alpha, these are generated by Fusion Forge every night, so the backup dir looks like this.

```
$ ls alpha-backup
cvsroot-tmp-2012-02-15.tar.bz2  etc-tmp-2012-02-15.tar.bz2          svn-repositories-2012-02-15
cvsroot-tmp-2012-02-16.tar.bz2  etc-tmp-2012-02-16.tar.bz2          svn-repositories-2012-02-16
db-alpha-tmp-2012-02-15.tar    mailinglist-tmp-2012-02-15.tar.bz2  uploads-tmp-2012-02-15.tar.bz2
db-alpha-tmp-2012-02-16.tar    mailinglist-tmp-2012-02-16.tar.bz2  uploads-tmp-2012-02-16.tar.bz2
```

Every night the a the new backup is created, and old one removed.  I've been trying to avoid modifying this process so far, as it's not my code.

Each svn-repositories directory contains about 200GB the rest are small in comparison.  So when svn-repositories-2012-02-16 is created it is very close to svn-repositories-2012-02-15 on the backup server but rsync doesn't appear be able find figure that out and only copy the changes.  I've tried several variation of arguments on rsync with little success, this is what is currently used.

```
rsync -aq -P --inplace --delete --fuzzy /alpha-backup/. beta::alpha
```

Anyways I'm looking for a something to fix this so my backups don't take forever.

Comment: I would set up a slave svn repository as a backup. Also, gzip can generate rsync friendly archives (not sure for bzip)

Comment: Thanks, I actually turned of the zipping of the SVN archives for this exact reason, I didn't realize that gzip has that feature, I'll have to enable it for the other files.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the svnsync command.

1. Create an empty repository:
   `svnadmin create c:\svn\backup_repo`
2. Enable propery changes:
   `echo exit 0 >> c:\svn\backup_repo\hooks\pre-revprop-change.bat`
3. Initialize backup:
   `svnsync init c:\svn\backup_repo <path_to_alpha_repo>`
4. Begin the sync:
   `svnsync sync file:///c:/svn/backup_repo`

The first time you run the sync (i.e. Step 4) it will probably take quite some time.  However, once you're synched to HEAD, you schedule a quick job to periodically run `svnsync sync file:///c:/svn/backup_repo` and your backup is always up to date.  It will be an exact replica of the original SVN repository, including the same revision IDs, log comments, etc.

Comment: Thank you, their are two issues.  First I have a bunch of repositories so I have to do this for each one and make a script to add new ones when they are added.  Also, I don't think this will sync all of the meta data, like user permissions, which change frequently :( .

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial solutions that address this with hot backups such as [Subversion Clustering](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/clustering) which work over a LAN or a WAN.